# Writing a CLI with NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, command-line-interface, nestjs

In the course [NestJS Fundamentals](https://learn.nestjs.com/courses/591712/lectures/10643066) (3:29), [Kamil Myśliwiec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6696689/kamil-my%C5%9Bliwiec) mentions that you can use NestJS to build CLI tools.

Is there any documentation on how to do this ? Any example that is available ? (I could not find anything on SO, searching the web for NestJS CLI yielded mostly links related to the built-in CLI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow the general setup in the [Standalone Application](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications) docs. You'd take in values from `process.argv` and pass it to your services as necessary

---

Expanding on this, there's also [nest-commander](https://nest-commander.jaymcdoniel.dev) which is a wrapper around the commander package with Nest's DI syntax and capabilities